# Callback function in a templated function accepting variable argument type using `switch` statement

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++14

I am trying to call a callback function from within a templated function. But the arguments for the callback function depend on `switch` statement.

Here's the working code which explains what I intend to do using a toy example.

```
#include <vector>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};

enum class StructType
{
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D
};

std::vector<A> vec_A;
std::vector<B> vec_B;
std::vector<C> vec_C;
std::vector<D> vec_D;


template <template <class> class Container, class ValueType>
void process(const StructType& struct_type)
{
  auto callback = [&](Container<ValueType>& v) {};

  switch(struct_type)
  {
    case StructType::A:
      callback(vec_A);
      break;
    case StructType::B:
      callback(vec_B);
      break;
    case StructType::C:
      callback(vec_C);
      break;
    case StructType::D:
      callback(vec_D);
      break;
  }
}


int main()
{
  process<std::vector, A>(StructType::A);

}
```

On compilation, I get the following error:

```
$ g++ template.cpp 
template.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void process(const StructType&) [with Iterator = std::vector; ValueType = A]’:
template.cpp:47:26:   required from here
template.cpp:33:15: error: no match for call to ‘(process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>) (std::vector<B>&)’
   33 |       callback(vec_B);
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
template.cpp:25:19: note: candidate: ‘process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>’
   25 |   auto callback = [&](Iterator<ValueType>& v) {};
      |                   ^
template.cpp:25:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<B>’ to ‘std::vector<A>&’
template.cpp:36:15: error: no match for call to ‘(process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>) (std::vector<C>&)’
   36 |       callback(vec_C);
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
template.cpp:25:19: note: candidate: ‘process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>’
   25 |   auto callback = [&](Iterator<ValueType>& v) {};
      |                   ^
template.cpp:25:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<C>’ to ‘std::vector<A>&’
template.cpp:39:15: error: no match for call to ‘(process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>) (std::vector<D>&)’
   39 |       callback(vec_D);
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
template.cpp:25:19: note: candidate: ‘process<std::vector, A>(const StructType&)::<lambda(std::vector<A>&)>’
   25 |   auto callback = [&](Iterator<ValueType>& v) {};
      |                   ^
template.cpp:25:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<D>’ to ‘std::vector<A>&’
```

My `g++` version is: `11.1.0`.

I can understand the error but just not sure how to fix this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT 1: `Iterator` -> `Container` for template type made more sense as suggested by @Ted Lyngmo.

Comment: You have an argument to the function that is only known at runtime but it depends on the compile time type in the template parameter. Do you really need the runtime argument in that case? [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/1nGMv7jeo) Unrelated: `Iterator` is a strange name for the template parameter. `Container` may be a better fit.

Comment: So, are you suggesting I just use `auto callback = [&](const auto& v) {};`? Because this doesn't compile using `-std=c++14` flag.

Comment: I'm questioning why you have to supply `StructType::A` to `process`. What should happen if you call it with `process<std::vector, A>(StructType::B);`?

Comment: This was just a toy example. In the actual implementation, `process` is being called with different types of `Struct`, I just wanted to simulate that behaviour here using `Struct::A` as an example. Or rather say, process is passed with a container which has different types of vector data that calls `callback`.

Comment: Calling with `process<std::vector, A>(StructType::B);` should be undefined behaviour. Though this isn't handled in my case.

Comment: So, from the argument to the function, `StructType::A` you know that it should use a `std::vector<A>` - but that information is already in the template parameters (like I showed in my example at the top). I still don't see the reason for providing the same information via a runtime argument.

Comment: That definitely works. But I am limited to writing my code in c++14. Is there an equivalent of it in C++14?

Comment: I see. Then would [this](https://godbolt.org/z/44sr9EE94) help?

Comment: That defintely works! Thank you.

Comment: Great, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your errors say, there are no matches for `callback` functors you haven't created.

I suggest removing the runtime argument to `process` and using the information you have in the function template parameters only.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
struct D {};

// enum class StructType {A, B, C, D }; // perhaps not needed anymore

std::vector<A> vec_A;
std::vector<B> vec_B;
std::vector<C> vec_C;
std::vector<D> vec_D;

template<class T> auto& get_vec();
template<> auto& get_vec<std::vector<A>>() { return vec_A; }
template<> auto& get_vec<std::vector<B>>() { return vec_B; }
template<> auto& get_vec<std::vector<C>>() { return vec_C; }
template<> auto& get_vec<std::vector<D>>() { return vec_D; }

template <template <class, class...> class Container, class ValueType>
void process() {
    using container_type = Container<ValueType>;

    auto callback = [&](container_type&) {};
    callback(get_vec<container_type>());
}

int main() {
    process<std::vector, A>();
}
```